# PowerGadgets alternatives

Tags: powershell

Are there any products similar to PowerGadgets by SoftwareFx ? I am looking at gauge controls that support powershell which support auto-refresh.

Answer (score 4):

Check the ShowUI module.

http://showui.codeplex.com
http://show-ui.com
http://huddledmasses.org/showui-tutorial-walkthrough